# Can you perform an equals comparison on most but not all class members with GSON's JsonElement

Tags: java, json, gson

I am writing an unit test with JUnit and I'm wondering if there is a way to perform an `assertEquals` comparison on it.

I have two JsonElement classes that I would like to compare but I would like to ignore a field in an array property inside the JSON.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
   "name":"Jon",
   "arrayProps":[
      {
         "careAbout":"123",
         "doNotCareAbout":"blablabla"
      },
      {
         "careAbout":"456",
         "doNotCareAbout":"blablabla"
      },
      {
         "careAbout":"789",
         "doNotCareAbout":"blablabla"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to compare all fields apart from the doNotCareAbout elements. Is this possible with GSON when I call:

```
JsonElement element1 = ...;
JsonElement element2 = ...;
assertEquals(element1, element2);
```

If it is not, can anybody recommend a suitable library where I can do this type of comparison where I would like exclude some elements?

Answer (score 1):

You could instead write a custom Comparator (or override `compareTo`) that ignores the element, and verify that `assertEquals(compare(element1, element2), 0);` or `assertEquals(element1.compareTo(element2), 0);`. Since you just want to see if they're equal it should be easy to iterate through the elements.

Better to use the comparator so you're not polluting your object with stuff specific to testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the "doNotCareAbout" property from each element in the "arrayProps" array like so:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) element;
JsonArray arrayProps = (JsonArray) jsonObject.get("arrayProps");
for (JsonElement arrayProp : arrayProps) {
    JsonObject arrayPropObject = (JsonObject) arrayProp;
    arrayPropObject.remove("doNotCareAbout");
}

System.out.println(jsonObject); // prints {"name":"Jon","arrayProps":[{"careAbout":"123"},{"careAbout":"456"},{"careAbout":"789"}]}
```

After doing this, you should be able to to compare the JsonElements in the way that you want.

Alternatively, you could look at using the [json-path](https://code.google.com/p/json-path/) library to extract just the properties that you want to compare:

```
String name = JsonPath.read(json, "$.name");
System.out.println(name); // prints Jon

List<String> careAboutProps = JsonPath.read(json, "$.arrayProps[*].careAbout");
System.out.println(careAboutProps); // prints ["123","456","789"]
```

However, this might not be feasible if the real elements of "arrayProps" have a lot of properties and you only want to exclude a few of them.

Comment: I also have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329227/how-to-serialize-json-to-another-json-by-preserving-data-types-of-key). See if you can help me out? Any help will be  appreciated on this.