# How to serialize json to another json by preserving data types of key?

Tags: java, json, string, serialization, gson

I have my original JSON String like this in which I have key and value as shown below -

```
{
  "u":{
     "string":"1235"
  },
  "p":"2047935",
  "client_id":{
     "string":"5"
  },
  "origin":null,
  "item_condition":null,
  "country_id":{
     "int":3
  },
  "timestamp":{
     "long":1417823759555
  },
  "impression_id":{
     "string":"2345HH*"
  },
  "is_consumerid":true,
  "is_pid":false
}
```

As an example, one key is `"u"` and its value is -

```
{
    "string":"1235"
}
```

Similarly another key is `"country_id"` and its value is -

```
{
    "int":3
}
```

Now what I need to do is, I need to represent key value pair as shown below. If any value is string data type (like value for key `u`), then represent it's value in double quotes, otherwise don't represent it's value in double quotes. Meaning value of country_id won't be in String double quotes since it is an int.

```
"u": "1235"
"p": "2047935"
"client_id": "5"
"origin":null
"item_condition":null
"country_id": 3 // I don't have double quotes here around 3 since country_id was int that's why
"timestamp": 1417823759555
"impression_id": "2345HH*"
"is_consumerid": true
"is_pid": false
```

And then I need to make another json string which should look like this -

```
{
    "u": "1235",
    "p": "2047935",
    "client_id": "5",
    "origin":null,
    "item_condition":null,
    "country_id": 3,
    "timestamp": 1417823759555,
    "impression_id": "2345HH*",
    "is_consumerid": true,
    "is_pid": false
}
```

So I started with below code but not able to understand what should I do further?

```
    String response = "original_json_string";
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(response).getAsJsonObject();

    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> object : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
        if (object.getValue() instanceof JsonObject) {
            String data = object.getValue().toString();
            // now not sure what should I do here?

        }
    }
```

And my new json should print out like this after serializing.

```
{
    "u": "1235",
    "p": "2047935",
    "client_id": "5",
    "origin":null,
    "item_condition":null,
    "country_id": 3,
    "timestamp": 1417823759555,
    "impression_id": "2345HH*",
    "is_consumerid": true,
    "is_pid": false
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please let me know if the original structure of JSON is fixed. I mean every time "client_id" will have "string" or it can also have "long" in any case ?

Comment: @ShaikhMohammedShariq Yes it is fixed. In short, if any key is string, they will always be string. And same goes with int, long, boolean as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I'm not yet very experienced with Gson, so there might be easiest ways to do it. Also this solution comes up after the discussion we had previously.

Basically the problem was to get the wanted type in the json file back (which is done by the `addEntry` method) and each @event key should have its own JSON string (done by `computeJson`). Since there are only two nested levels, it's fine to do it like that. Otherwise a recursive approach will do the trick.

So if you have only one nested level, you should iterate other the JsonObject's entries'. For each entries, `computeJson` will add a new Json entry in the List which corresponds to each `@event` key.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader("myJson.json")).getAsJsonObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> object : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
            if (object.getValue() instanceof JsonObject) {
                output.add(computeJson((JsonObject)object.getValue()));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    private static String computeJson(JsonObject source) {
        JsonObject output = new JsonObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> object : source.entrySet()) {
            if (object.getValue() instanceof JsonObject) {
                for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : ((JsonObject)object.getValue()).entrySet()) {
                    addEntry(object.getKey(), output, entry);
                }
            } else {
                addEntry(object.getKey(), output, object);
            }
        }
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        return gson.toJson(output);
    }

    private static void addEntry(String key, JsonObject output, Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> object) {
        switch(object.getKey().toLowerCase()) {
            case "string":
                output.addProperty(key, object.getValue().getAsString());
                break;
            case "int":
                output.addProperty(key, object.getValue().getAsInt());
                break;
            case "long":
                output.addProperty(key, object.getValue().getAsLong());
                break;
            //add other primitive cases
            default:
                output.add(key, object.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is much neat solution than what I have posted below. +1

Comment: It works  like a charm. Thanks a  lot for the help. I am going to run some more test on it with various Json.

Answer (score 0):

As described here [RawCollectionsExample](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/extras/examples/rawcollections/RawCollectionsExample.java) you can manually parse the json and set it in the desired object. Once values are parsed and set you can again serialize the java object to have desired json.

For setting values from your json you need to have POJO shown below.

```
public class CustomObject {

    private String u;
    private String p;
    private String client_id;
    private String origin;
    private String item_condition;
    private int country_id;
    private long timestamp;
    private String impression_id;
    private boolean is_consumerid;
    private boolean is_pid;
    public String getU() {
        return u;
    }
    public void setU(String u) {
        this.u = u;
    }
    public String getP() {
        return p;
    }
    public void setP(String p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
    public String getClient_id() {
        return client_id;
    }
    public void setClient_id(String clientId) {
        client_id = clientId;
    }
    public String getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }
    public void setOrigin(String origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }
    public String getItem_condition() {
        return item_condition;
    }
    public void setItem_condition(String itemCondition) {
        item_condition = itemCondition;
    }
    public int getCountry_id() {
        return country_id;
    }
    public void setCountry_id(int countryId) {
        country_id = countryId;
    }
    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    public String getImpression_id() {
        return impression_id;
    }
    public void setImpression_id(String impressionId) {
        impression_id = impressionId;
    }
    public boolean isIs_consumerid() {
        return is_consumerid;
    }
    public void setIs_consumerid(boolean isConsumerid) {
        is_consumerid = isConsumerid;
    }
    public boolean isIs_pid() {
        return is_pid;
    }
    public void setIs_pid(boolean isPid) {
        is_pid = isPid;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomObject [client_id=" + client_id + ", country_id="
                + country_id + ", impression_id=" + impression_id
                + ", is_consumerid=" + is_consumerid + ", is_pid=" + is_pid
                + ", item_condition=" + item_condition + ", origin=" + origin
                + ", p=" + p + ", timestamp=" + timestamp + ", u=" + u + "]";
    }

}
```

In above POJO you can parse and set JSON value manually as shown below :

```
String jsonLine = "{  \"u\":{     \"string\":\"1235\"  },  \"p\":\"2047935\",  \"client_id\":{     \"string\":\"5\"  },  \"origin\":null,  \"item_condition\":null,  \"country_id\":{     \"int\":3  },  \"timestamp\":{     \"long\":1417823759555  },  \"impression_id\":{     \"string\":\"2345HH*\"  },  \"is_consumerid\":true,  \"is_pid\":false}";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

//in case you have json array you need to use .getAsJsonArray instead of getAsJsonObject
JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(jsonLine).getAsJsonObject();
CustomObject obj = new CustomObject();

obj.setP(jsonObject.get("p").getAsString());
obj.setU(jsonObject.get("u").getAsJsonObject().get("string").getAsString());
obj.setClient_id(jsonObject.get("client_id").getAsJsonObject().get("string").getAsString());

//null check which will be required for each value in case there are possibility of having null values
String origin = jsonObject.get("origin").isJsonNull() ==true?null:jsonObject.get("origin").getAsString();
obj.setOrigin(origin);
String itemCondition = jsonObject.get("item_condition").isJsonNull() ==true?null:jsonObject.get("item_condition").getAsString();
obj.setItem_condition(itemCondition);
obj.setCountry_id(jsonObject.get("country_id").getAsJsonObject().get("int").getAsInt());
obj.setTimestamp(jsonObject.get("timestamp").getAsJsonObject().get("long").getAsLong());
obj.setImpression_id(jsonObject.get("impression_id").getAsJsonObject().get("string").getAsString());
obj.setIs_consumerid(jsonObject.get("is_consumerid").getAsBoolean());
obj.setIs_pid(jsonObject.get("is_consumerid").getAsBoolean());
System.out.println("JSON OUTPUT "+ new Gson().toJson(obj));
```

You can run the code snippet in any class's main method to validate. Check the last line above which outputs required json. Let me know if this is not what you were looking for.